# Unable to compile class for JSP: x cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, jsp, import

I've looked through numerous similar posts and tried a number of solutions over the past couple days. None have worked.

I typically don't work with Java but the main Java guy on my team is out of the office for a couple weeks and I would like to finish a project during that time.

Here's the issue:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page session="false"%>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@page import="java.io.File" %>
<%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream" %>
<%@page import="java.util.Properties" %>

<%@page import="a.custom.package.path.FilterVO" %>
<%@page import="a.custom.package.path.CodeTypeSearchResultsDTO" %>
<%@page import="a.custom.package.path.CodeDTO" %>

<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Code in question begin ======================================== -->
        <%
            // Create filter.
            FilterVO filter = new FilterVO();
            filter.setActive(true);


            // Execute search.
            CodeSearchResultsDTO results = getMyClient().getSystemFacade().getSomePreferences(filter, new Range(1, 10), "");

            for (CodeDTO code : results.getCodes())
            {
                System.out.println("Some Preference: " + code);
            }
        %>
        <!-- Code in question end ========================================== -->



        <!-- Some CSS imports and JS imports are here. -->

        <%
            <!-- Some currently working java code here that references the first 3 java imports at the top of the page. -->
        %>

    </head>
   <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the errors:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 28 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
CodeSearchResultsDTO cannot be resolved to a type
25: 
26: 
27:             // Execute search.
28:             CodeSearchResultsDTO results = getMyClient().getSystemFacade().getSomePreferences(filter, new Range(1, 10), "");
29: 
30:             for (CodeDTO code : results.getCodes())
31:             {


An error occurred at line: 28 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
The method getMyClient() is undefined for the type index_jsp
25: 
26: 
27:             // Execute search.
28:             CodeSearchResultsDTO results = getMyClient().getSystemFacade().getSomePreferences(filter, new Range(1, 10), "");
29: 
30:             for (CodeDTO code : results.getCodes())
31:             {


An error occurred at line: 28 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Range cannot be resolved to a type
25: 
26: 
27:             // Execute search.
28:             CodeSearchResultsDTO results = getMyClient().getSystemFacade().getSomePreferences(filter, new Range(1, 10), "");
29: 
30:             for (CodeDTO code : results.getCodes())
31:             {


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:460)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

The classes are located in the WEB-INF/lib jar's, as in they are not missing. The path is correct. The casing is correct. I've tried to 'clean' my container by deleting the CATALINA_BASE/work/Catalina/localhost folder. I've tried to clean all browser cash because that was suggested for some reason (seemed like a long shot).

I'm leaning towards it being a container java dependency refresh issue, but again, Java and containers aren't exactly my MO.

I realize now I haven't imported the Range class, which I will add, but that wont stop the main issue of these imports not being found.

Any debugging advice would be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Comment: You are not importing Range, also this is a very bad way of writing JSP

Comment: I mentioned the lack of the Range import... I also did not architect this app and realize java code should not be in a JSP page, but that's a battle I will have to fight another day. All I need to know is if what I'm trying to do, is impossible, or just bad practice... and then I need to know how to make it work :)

Comment: I guess not importing range might be the actual cause of the issue... will check now.

Comment: Does the custom type class has the required field when getSomepreference is returned? can you post the method for getSomePreferences

Comment: Another aspect making this difficult is that I don't currently have access to the java source code. I think I'll need to get that at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something is wrong here.

This is what you import

```
<%@page import="a.custom.package.path.CodeTypeSearchResultsDTO" %>
```

This is what you call

```
CodeSearchResultsDTO
```

Could it be a Typ(e)o ??

Comment: This is definitely the/an issue. That's what I get for asking another dev to send me the full class name path's instead of figuring out where they were on my own. Thanks Angelo!

Comment: In addition to that you might want to check what the getMyClients() method is called on...is it meant to come from a static import? Not too sure you can do that on a jsp...

Comment: I also just noticed that, and thats the next error. This code snippet that was given to me doesn't seem to have the support it needs. Not even sure what class the getMyClients() belongs to, and I don't have access to the source. SadFace.

Comment: You could try and see if he used the same method in another jsp... anyway good luck and remember to tell your dev to stop using scriplets